# Keep previous updated Item in PagedListAdapter after List has been updated from DataSource

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, page-library

I have a `RecyclerView` that uses a `PagedListAdapter` which fetches data from `ROOM` and Network API. It uses a `BoundaryCallback` to make request to the API of which the data returned is inserted into the Database(ROOM)

I have a list item that has an increment and decrement button...
[image]

The current list is filterable, e.g i can filter the list of products by multiple categories

**Problem**

If i increase a product item `quantity` using the increment button, to e.g 12 and then i try filter the list by adding more category, the current list doesn't refresh which is fine because the DiffUtil.ItemCallback confirms that the items are the same, but once i try to increment that same product's quantity after filtering by more category, it starts from zero again....

Note that quantity is not a column in room, it's an Ignored variable.

So i'm not really sure what the problem really is: below is the code that does the increment and decrement.

```
override fun onIncrementQuantity(position: Int, item: ProductEntity) {
    item.quantity = item.quantity + 1
    selectedProducts[item.item.id!!] = item
    productAdapter?.notifyItemChanged(position, item)
}
override fun onDecrementQuantity(position: Int, item: ProductEntity) {
    item.quantity = if (item.quantity == 0) 0 else item.quantity - 1
    if (item.quantity == 0) {
        selectedProducts.remove(item.item.id)
    } else {
        selectedProducts[item.item.id!!] = item
    }
    productAdapter?.notifyItemChanged(position, item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of debugging here is what i found out.

- List is initially loaded with data
- updates are done on the current data e.g increment `item.quantity = 2`
- Once new data is fetched (through search or filters), onBindViewHolder is NOT called if the **itemsAretheSame** or the **ContentsAreThemSame** thus no need to update the view. Everything at this point is fine.

However, it seems the currentList has been updated to the newly fetched data without necessarily updating the view... Now, when `notifyItemChanged` is called, onBindViewHolder is triggered:

This is how my `onBindViewHolder` is

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder<T>, position: Int) {
    getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
}
```

`getItem(position)` gives you the item from the current list which has been updated and quantity is back to default 0.

**Solution**

Override the below function of the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: ViewHolder<ProductEntity>, 
    pos: Int, 
    payloads: MutableList<Any>
) { 
    if(payloads.isEmpty()) return super.onBindViewHolder(holder, pos, payloads)
    val product = getItem(pos)?: return
    payloads.forEach {
       val oldProduct = it as ProductEntity
       if(product.item.id == oldProduct.item.id){
          product.quauntity = oldProduct.quantity
       }
    }
}
```

The payload should include the partial old data which can be used to update the new data..

According to the documentation

```
     * The payloads parameter is a merge list from {@link #notifyItemChanged(int, Object)} or
     * {@link #notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int, Object)}.  If the payloads list is not empty,
     * the ViewHolder is currently bound to old data and Adapter may run an efficient partial
     * update using the payload info.  If the payload is empty,  Adapter must run a full bind.
     * Adapter should not assume that the payload passed in notify methods will be received by
     * onBindViewHolder().  For example when the view is not attached to the screen, the
     * payload in notifyItemChange() will be simply dropped.
```